# ui-grid highlight row while enableRowSelection is false

Tags: angularjs, highlight, ui-grid

I'm working with angularjs but i have a problem with my ng-grid.

First, the client didn't want the user to select a row just by clicking it.
They wanted a single checkbox at the beginning of the row.
To do that i had to disable the row selection by doing this :
"enableFullRowSelection: false". This prevented the row to be selected.

But now they want me to allow the highlight of the row by clicking it.
I tried to put a css focus but the event never triggered (i tried hover and mouseenter and the css worked).

How can i disable the row but still let the focus event enable ?

If someone can help me it will unstuck me !

Comment: Please post demo in fiddle/plunkr

Comment: I don't know how to use Plunker yet.
I made the basic : https://plnkr.co/edit/UVOVcxv9OVb9gtW1f3Sg
But it seems it missing some fundamentals to execute.

Comment: Customise your `rowTemplate`. Add an ng-click to that template and upon selecting the row, assign the row.entity to a variable, use ng-class to append a class by comparing if that row is the selected one and append a class which will set a background color.